# Adding Keybinds to Windows10 Right-Click Context Menu?

Tags: windows, contextmenu, key-bindings, right-click, personalization

I work at a Japanese company and we all use Windows 10. I am used to using keybinds after rightclicking for a pop up Context Menu. At home, my PC does not show any keybind options when I do the same thing.

The Japanese image below in not mine, but an example for reference. You can see that "Eject" (取り出し) has a keybind marked as (J).

Is there any option to add this feature to my PC? I have searched everywhere to no avail.

With Keybinds
[image]

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

Without Keybinds [image]

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are there but hidden by default when you use the mouse. If you open the context menu with the keyboard (the context menu key or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) then they should be underlined.

> Starting with Windows 2000, keyboard indicators such as underlined accelerators and focus rectangles (collectively known as “keyboard cues”) are [hidden by default](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050503-00/?p=35723), and are revealed only when you start using the keyboard. You can control this behavior from the Desktop Control Panel, under Appearance, Effects, “Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the Alt key”.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know that they still work, I was just concerned as to why  they no longer appeared as I prefer their presence.